# Obtener hora del servidor con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, date

Buenas tarde tengo una web con angular y c# y estoy intentando obtener la hora del servidor pero me devuelve la hora utc en vez de la hora del servidor.
Este es el codigo:

```
function getServerTime() {
            return $.ajax({ async: false }).getResponseHeader('Date');
        }
console.log('Server Time: ', getServerTime());
console.log('Locale Time: ', new Date(getServerTime()));
```

Y esto lo que devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servidor está en España así que la hora local y la del servidor deberían de ser la misma

Comment: Son la misma. Una es UTC (GMT), la que llamas "server" y la otra está en zona UTC+2 (la que llamas "local"). Eso significa que si restas las 2 horas demás que se indica en la de "local", te dará exactamente la misma hora que "server". Para ver ambas horas en formato UTC, deberías usar en ambas fechas (suponiendo que son dos valores tipo Date) el método [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString). Saludos

Comment: Cual consideras que debe de ser la hora correcta del servidor??? por ejemplo si tienes tu host en china; muy probablemente el servidor tenga la hora de ese pais ... y no tu hora latina...

Comment: El servidor está en España y yo estoy en España así que la hora debería de ser la misma

Comment: Lo que yo quiero es que me muestra la hora del servidor no la hora utc

Answer (score 0):

En C# tienes dos funciones que retornan la hora actual

- DateTime.Now; // devuelve la hora local
- DateTime.UtcNow; //devuelve la hora local con UTC-0

En javascript tienes

- new Date() // hora local
- (new Date()).toUTCString() // UTC-0 - formato
  'Fri, 16 Sep 2022 17:24:01 GMT'
- (new Date()).toISOString() // UTC-0 - formato '2022-09-16T17:24:40.790Z'